# Flutter build runner - Enable / disabled builders through command line

Tags: flutter, flutter-build, build-runner

I'm on a Flutter project and we are using [`build_runner`](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner).

We are using several builders and runnning all of them takes a long time.
Our file looks like this:

```yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      package1|builder1:
        # ... options package1
      package2|builder2:
        # ... options package2
      package3|builder3:
        # ... options package3

      # ... A bunch of other packages

      packageN|builderN:
        # ... options packageN
```

---

Now let's say I applied some changes in the project and I need to run the builders.
But I know, only some builders need to be run and not the others (let's say `builder2` and `builder3`).

Right now, when I run

```
flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs
```

It is running all the builders and it takes a very long time.

---

Is there a way to run specific builders with a command line?

Comment: You mean disable all by default and only enable the ones you specify? All I've seen is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72879685/5881647